# How does the Silverlight testing framework's EnqueueConditional work?

Tags: silverlight, unit-testing

So let's say I have a test that looks something like

```
[TestMethod]
[Asynchronous]
public void MyTest() {

    MyObject m = new MyObject();
    m.DoAsyncStuff();

    EnqueueConditional(() => m.TaskComplete);
    EnqueueCallback(() => Assert.IsTrue(m.ValidState));
    EnqueueTestComplete();
}
```

How does `EnqueueConditional` work? Assume `MyObject` has no property change notifiers or anything. I'm assuming `EnqueueConditional` polls the variable periodically? But I'm not sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's precisely what it does. It polls the `m.TaskComplete` variable multiple times a second (I'm not sure how many). It's a hack, and you wouldn't want it in production code, but it works for a testing framework, and it sure as heck simplifies a lot of other code.

For example, in production code, you'd probably want to make MyObject implement INotifyPropertyChanged, and then use Reactive Extensions to subscribe to the INPC notifications. But that would be a lot of extra work for the sort of simple conditionals that are everywhere in testing code, and I think that Jeff Wilcox made the right call in how he implemented this, however hacky it might be.

Comment: Thanks man, how did you find this out? .NET Reflector? I started going through that but couldn't justify spending too much work time on it for my own curiosity :P

Comment: I poked around through the source code a while back - it comes with the Silverlight Toolkit. And I believe I recall Jeff Wilcox confirming something similar in an earlier question, though I wasn't able to find it just now.

Comment: Never mind, found it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1905353/waiting-for-event-triggering-in-silverlight-unit-tests

Comment: Hah, I didn't even realize it was open source. What a dope.