# Silverlight async unit testing

Tags: silverlight, unit-testing, silverlight-toolkit, silverlight-5.0

I'm having a weird issue with Silverlight Unit Test Framework. The very first method executed fails, every time. I have a second test with the exact same code, and it passes. The strange thing about the first time it's called is that it actually waits for the timeout *and then* executes the repository call (underneath it's an HTTP PUT if you care). Here's the code - the first one fails every time, second one passes every time:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void AuthShouldSucceed()
    {
        var autoResetEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);

        _authRepository.Authenticate(_username, _password, response =>
        {
            Assert.IsTrue(response);
            autoResetEvent.Set();
        });
        if (!autoResetEvent.WaitOne(Constants.Timeout))
        {
            Assert.Fail("Test timed out.");
        } 
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void AuthShouldSucceed2()
    {
        var autoResetEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);

        _authRepository.Authenticate(_username, _password, response =>
        {
            Assert.IsTrue(response);
            autoResetEvent.Set();
        });
        if (!autoResetEvent.WaitOne(Constants.Timeout))
        {
            Assert.Fail("Test timed out.");
        } 
    }
```

**Edit:**
My final solution is a modification of Vladmir's solution:

```
    [TestMethod]
    [Asynchronous]
    public void AuthShouldSucceed()
    {
        var complete = false;
        var result = false;

        _authRepository.Authenticate(_username, _password, response =>
        {
            complete = true;
            result = response;
        });

        EnqueueConditional(() => complete);
        EnqueueCallback(() => Assert.IsTrue(result));
        EnqueueTestComplete();
    }
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you're using Silverlight Unit Tests Framework try to rewrite your test next way:

```
    [TestMethod]
    [Asynchronous]
    public void AuthShouldSucceed()
    {
        var done = false;
        var authResult = false;
        _authRepository.Authenticate(_username, _password, response =>
        {
            var done = true;
            authResult = response;
        });

        EnqueueConditional(() => done);
        EnqueueCallback(() => Assert.IsTrue(authResult));
        EnqueueTestComplete();
    }
```

Your test class should be derived from SilverlightTest class:

```
[TestClass]
public class MyTests: SilverlightTest
```

Comment: This is awesome with one thing I'd change. This works because `Authenticate` coincidentally returns `true`. If I was testing for `false` or it returned some other object it wouldn't work. Basically I modified this answer to work regardless of return type - I used a `done` variable like supra suggested (along with the result variable).

Answer (score 4):

Summarizing all written you should be aware of couple important points in writing Unit Tests for Silverlight.

---

**`[Asynchronous]`**
Attribute of test method shows that you are testing part which includes async operations and want to syncronize them for testing purposes. Asynchrony itself in Silverlight Unit Tests Framework is a bit distorted. All "Enqueue" directives are like "postpone this until something happens" which is not a sense which the traditional programming asynchrony meaning has.

---

**`EnqueueConditional`** 

Otherwords means wait until condition will be met. And this is one of the most important parts of async tests. After condition becomes legal all `EnqueueCallbacks` until the next `EnqueueConditional` will be executed.

[*Important note:*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1905353/waiting-for-event-triggering-in-silverlight-unit-tests)

> `EnqueueConditional` repeatedly calls the predicate passed to it on a
>   timer/background thread, checking each time to see if it returns true.

That's why you should avoid using heavy, complex logic within conditions.

---

**`EnqueueCallback`** 

Defers code execution until `EnqueueConditional` that precedes it will met condition. It enqueues an `Actoin` or an array of `Actions`.

---

**`EnqueueDelay`** 
Enqueues minimum number of milliseconds/time delay before continuing.

---

**`EnqueueTestComplete`**
Enqueues an action to call **`TestComplete`** which signals that a test is complete when using Async testing.

*Important Note(from documentation):*

> If you use your own methods for completing, such as an HtmlTimer or
>   other threading method, it is possible that this call will occur
>   *AFTER* the test has timed out when using Timeouts. As such, be very careful as you could complete the call to the *next* test.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Asynchronous keyword in the TestMethod

```
[TestMethod]
[Asynchronous]
[Description("This test checks when NULL is passed")]

public void Testing()
{
 bool done = false;
 EnvViewModel test = new EnvViewModel ();
 .
 .

 test.AsyncCallBackCompleted += (() => done = true);

 EnqueueCallback(() => test.DataCommand.Execute(null));
 EnqueueConditional(() => done);
 EnqueueCallback(() => Assert.IsTrue(test.AADTDecisionModelList.Count == 0, 
                                             "The result does not have any data."));

 EnqueueTestComplete();
}
```

And make a delegate in the ViewModel to be used to every method that is being tested...

```
public delegate void AsynCallComplete();
public event AsynCallComplete AsyncCallBackCompleted;
public void InformCallbackCompleted()
{
     if (AsyncCallBackCompleted != null)
     {
          AsyncCallBackCompleted();
     }
}
```